# htaccess redirect of urls from an old domain that is now parked

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I had an old website that was on a .com domain. 
This domain is now parked and is forwarding to the new domain.
The new domain is `.com.au` and I have to place my `.htaccess` file there.

I am trying to re-direct all urls coming from the old domain to the homepage of the new domain.
So anything like `olddomain.com/index.php?option=...` etc should just go to `newdomian.com.au`

**Nothing of the old url path should be carried across.**

I have tried many ways to get things working, the nearest I get is:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?olddomian.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newdomain.com.au [R=301,L]
```

But I am getting the url path being carried across to the new domain and that is giving an 404 error.
That is, I am getting from this: olddomain.com/index.php?option=... to this: newdomain.com.au/index.php?option=...

What do I need to do to stop the URL path from being carried across?
Please note both domains are on the same webserver, but the old one is parked and does not have any hosting allocated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to include a preceding rule, which will detect if the old domain uri contains a query string and, if so, eliminates it.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?olddomain.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.+)
RewriteRule .* http://%{HTTP_HOST}/? [NC]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?olddomain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newdomain.com.au [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thank you, those rules work perfectly, every url is re-directed to the home page.